# What happens to a disposable FFP2/N95 respirator during the prolonged use?

Tags: covid-19, face-mask-respirator

## Background

The area I live in has a regulation that people should wear PPE when visiting grocery stores, etc. There is a shortage of PPE. I have access to some non-reusable FFP2-class respirators that are intended to be used during a 8 hours shift (similar to [this one](https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/company-us/all-3m-products/%7E/3M-VFlex-Particulate-Respirator-9105S-N95-Small-400-EA-Case/?N=5002385+3294756851&rt=rud)).
Reuse of disposable respirators [has been suggested](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/hcp/ppe-strategy/decontamination-reuse-respirators.html) as a crisis measure during the shortage. I have been reusing my respirators for a while, but by now I have used each of them for more than 8 hours.

Until I can replenish my stock, I have a choice between using the repsirators beyond the designated 8 hours, or resort to cloth masks, which are widely available / widely used in my area. A cloth mask is basically nothing more than a piece of cloth that can be attached to one's face.

## My research so far

I'm by no means an expert, so correct me if I'm wrong. From what I understand cloth masks offer almost no protection against viruses. Respirators, on the other hand, offer some degree of protection due to being able to filter out particles/droplets from the inhaled air thanks to the [electrostatic charge of the filter material](https://www.uvex-safety.com/blog/how-do-respirators-actually-work/). However, I wasn't able to find any info on the following:

## Question

**What happens to the respirator during the prolonged use?**

Why is the use time limited? Is it because the contamination of filter layers reduces the electrostatic charge?

Most importantly, **can a respirator at some point become less useful / more harmful than a cloth mask?** (assuming that the user knows how to don/doff and store the respirators properly).

Comment: Does [this](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/21593/why-arent-we-sterilizing-n95-masks) answer your question? It's not _exactly_ a duplicate, but any answer to this question would largely duplicate the answers to that question.

Comment: @CareyGregory Thank you. Unfortunately it doesn't really answer my question. It contains various suggestions on how to sterilize the respirators, whereas I am more interested in how prolonged use affects the filtering properties of the respirator.